# docker terminal: waiting for an IP

Tags: docker

when I launch my docker quickstart terminal, It was clogged by "waiting for an IP" and no response at all.

Could someone tell me how to deal with?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I managed to get past the problem through the following steps:

- Start the `Oracle VM VirtualBox` desktop application.
- Select and manually start `default` virtual machine.
- Close virtual machine window and choose to `Send shutdown signal`.
- Run `Docker Quickstart Terminal`.
- *(optional)* Right-click on `default` virtual machine and select `Show`in the `Oracle VM VirtualBox` desktop application to monitor virtual machine boot process.

After performing the steps above, I the `Docker Quickstart Terminal` window displayed:

```
                    ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/

docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

Start interactive shell
...
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an older thread but this is what worked for me in Windows 10 Home with Docker Toolbox. Docker was stuck in "Waiting for an IP".

1. Close all docker terminals.
2. Open VirtualBox, shut the docker instance down 
   (if running), and remove it.
3. Start Docker Quickstart Terminal with Administrator Rights and wait for it to set everything up. This is the step that docker was previously getting stuck in.
4. (Optional) If you are curious to see what is happening behind the scenes, you can choose "Show" on the (now 'running') docker VM in VirtualBox.
5. Once 'docker' finishes booting, you can close the docker terminal and run it again without Admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

It looks your 'default' Virtual Machine of VirtualBox has wrong Network Adapter configuration. Try to check it first.

If it is your first run or you don't have any important Docker Images or Containers you can remove 'default' VM from VirtualBox. The Docker Quickstart Terminal re-create this 'default' virtual machine after starting.

Comment: that happens way to often to be convenient to recreate

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar problem and found the solution here

**https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/734#issuecomment-369910154**

I only did this

**Opened task manger and ended tasks to all Virtual Box instances.**