# Docker can connect to engine, but docker compose cannot

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-server-2019

I'm running Docker from within a container, which I start like so:

```
docker run -d `
  -v //./pipe/docker_engine://./pipe/docker_engine `
  -v "$($dockerpath):C:/docker"
```

From within the container, I can run `docker ps` just fine and it returns the running containers on the host engine.

However, when I run `docker-compose`, I get the error:

> Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to start Docker for Windows.

This worked fine back when I used TCP/TLS to connect to the Docker engine.  The problem started when I switched to using named pipes.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: I filed a ticket on this as well - https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4012

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this post: I had the same problem. I'm using docker-toolbox and noticed an error message in the terminal:

```
Error getting IP address: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show dev eth1
err : exit status 255
output : 
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
```

The solution was to reconfigure the default virtual machine. Run these commands in a terminal:

```
$ docker-machine rm default
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

Then run Docker Quickstart Terminal.

BTW, if you then come across an issue that the docker start is stuck at "Waiting for ip..." please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958619/docker-terminal-waiting-for-an-ip) post for the solution.